# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: android, google-maps

please guide what mistake am i doing here?
any help would be appreciated.

```
private void LoopThroughEachATMToDisplayOnMap()
           {


               Drawable drawable = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < atm.getAtmList().size(); i++) {

                    if(breakFlag)
                        break;

                    drawable = getAppropriatePin(i);
                    if(drawable == null) 
                    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
                    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView);

                    ATM a = atm.getAtmList().get(i);
                    if (a != null) {
                        int[] coordinates = getIntCoordinates(a
                                .getCoordinates());
                        if (coordinates != null) {
                            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(coordinates[0],
                                    coordinates[1]);
                            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(
                                    point, a.getBankName(), a.getAddress()
                                            + "@@" + a.getPhone() + "@@"
                                            + a.getWebAddress() + "@@"
                                            + a.getCoordinates());
                            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
                            System.out
                                    .println("coordinates-------------------------"
                                            + i + " "
                                            + coordinates[0]
                                            + ","
                                            + coordinates[1]);
                        }

                    }
                    if(mapOverlays == null)
                        mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

                    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
                }
                System.out.println("atms maps injection complete--------------------------------");

           }    

    06-09 18:41:12.019: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:64)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:44)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6535)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1585)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1312)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1585)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1312)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1585)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1312)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1866)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1364)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1118)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1650)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
    06-09 18:41:12.149: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13973):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you're doing smting like this `ArrayList<int> arr = new ArrayList<int>(); arr.add(1); arr.add(2); arr.add(3);   /* from here */ for(int i:arr){arr.add(5);}` ... in other word you modify collection when you iterate it

Comment: i am not modifying collection anywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got answer my self.

actually  mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay); needs ui to run.

so it was not ui thread thats why it was raising error.

i just ran that function in uithread and which resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay) needing UI to run.  I am trying to use it in an AsyncTask and doing the mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay) in the onPostExecute method since that provides UI access.  However, clicking on the overlay item crashes the app with the message: "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application".  What is the correct way to add the overlays in an AsyncTask?  BTW, I should mention, the overlay items worked just fine before I moved to the AsyncTask approach.

Comment: This will certainly fix the error. However, the correct answer will say that because you are adding elements to your mapOverlays array in more than one Thread, you need to prevent several Threads froma adding to your array at the same time. Using the UI thread fixes the error, because there's only one UI thread, and by forcing the usage of it, you prevent many threads from writing in mapOverlays array, only UI thread will do.